# Neo4j Server Issue- Shutting down abruptly on amazon Ec2 machine

Tags: amazon-ec2, neo4j

From Last 1 year we have been using neo4j in our project version - 2.2.3 recenlty we updated the neo4j to the latest stable version i.e 3.1.6. Our neo4j server is installed on Amazon Ec2 .

It was working fine few days back till we had the older version of  neo4j server and worked fine with the new version for 2-3 days but from yesterday don't know how but the neo4j stops working , we are unable to acess our data as well as the database browser UI. On the terminal of the Ec2 machine it shows status Running.

Here are the error log:

```
  2017-08-08 13:15:55.387+0000 WARN  HttpConnection@2dbbbcf3{FILLING} s=DISPATCHED i=true a=null

java.lang.IllegalStateException: s=DISPATCHED i=true a=null

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelState.handling(HttpChannelState.java:232)

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:282)

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)

at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)

at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)

at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2017-08-08 13:15:55.388+0000 WARN  HttpConnection@775f86ef{FILLING} s=DISPATCHED i=true a=null

java.lang.IllegalStateException: s=DISPATCHED i=true a=null

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelState.handling(HttpChannelState.java:232)

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:282)

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)

at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)

at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)

at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2017-08-08 13:15:55.389+0000 WARN  HttpConnection@29f5e5f9{FILLING} s=DISPATCHED i=true a=null

java.lang.IllegalStateException: s=DISPATCHED i=true a=null

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelState.handling(HttpChannelState.java:232)

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:282)

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)

at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)

at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)

at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2017-08-08 13:16:25.604+0000 WARN  {} Couldn't stop {}

2017-08-08 13:16:25.604+0000 WARN  {} Couldn't stop {}

2017-08-08 13:16:25.604+0000 WARN  {} Couldn't stop {}

2017-08-08 13:16:25.604+0000 WARN  {} Couldn't stop {}

2017-08-08 13:16:25.604+0000 WARN  {} Couldn't stop {}

2017-08-08 13:16:25.604+0000 WARN  {} Couldn't stop {}

2017-08-08 13:16:25.604+0000 WARN  {} Couldn't stop {}

2017-08-08 13:16:25.604+0000 WARN  {} Couldn't stop {}

2017-08-08 13:16:25.616+0000 INFO  Stopping...

2017-08-08 13:16:35.744+0000 ERROR Failed to rollback transaction. This database is shutdown.

org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.ThreadToStatementContextBridge$BridgeDatabaseShutdownException: This database is shutdown.

at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.checkIfShutdown(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:97)

at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.getKernelTransactionBoundToThisThread(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:113)

at org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransitionalTxManagementKernelTransaction.rollback(TransitionalTxManagementKernelTransaction.java:77)

at org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionHandle.closeContextAndCollectErrors(TransactionHandle.java:269)

at org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionHandle.commit(TransactionHandle.java:158)

at org.neo4j.server.rest.web.TransactionalService.lambda$executeStatementsAndCommit$1(TransactionalService.java:216)

at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(StreamingOutputProvider.java:71)

at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(StreamingOutputProvider.java:57)

at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:302)

at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1510)

at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)

at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)

at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)

at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)

at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)

at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)

at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)

at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)

at org.neo4j.server.rest.dbms.AuthorizationEnabledFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationEnabledFilter.java:122)

at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)

at org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CollectUserAgentFilter.doFilter(CollectUserAgentFilter.java:69)

at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)

at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)

at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)

at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)

at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)

at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Exception in thread "Thread-9" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.RecordStorageEngine@4186f001' failed to transition from stopped to shutting_down. Please see the attached cause exception "FileLock invalidated by an external force: NativeFSLock(path=/opt/neo4j-community-3.1.6/data/databases/graph.db/schema/label/lucene/labelStore/1/write.lock,impl=sun.nio.ch.FileLockImpl[0:9223372036854775807 exclusive invalid],ctime=2017-08-03T11:49:56.145951Z)".

at org.neo4j.helpers.RunCarefully.run(RunCarefully.java:57)

at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.stop(AbstractNeoServer.java:430)

at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper$1.run(ServerBootstrapper.java:180)

Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.RecordStorageEngine@4186f001' failed to transition from stopped to shutting_down. Please see the attached cause exception "FileLock invalidated by an external force: NativeFSLock(path=/opt/neo4j-community-3.1.6/data/databases/graph.db/schema/label/lucene/labelStore/1/write.lock,impl=sun.nio.ch.FileLockImpl[0:9223372036854775807 exclusive invalid],ctime=2017-08-03T11:49:56.145951Z)".

at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:496)

at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:206)

at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.stop(NeoStoreDataSource.java:895)

at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:457)

at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stopInstances(LifeSupport.java:161)

at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:143)

at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.stop(DataSourceManager.java:120)

at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:457)

at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stopInstances(LifeSupport.java:161)

at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:143)

at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:191)

at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.ClassicCoreSPI.shutdown(ClassicCoreSPI.java:158)

at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.shutdown(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:365)

at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.stop(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:106)

at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:457)

at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stopInstances(LifeSupport.java:161)

at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:143)

at org.neo4j.helpers.RunCarefully.run(RunCarefully.java:47)

... 2 more

Suppressed: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.pagecache.PageCacheLifecycle@68fbc432' failed to transition from stopped to shutting_down. Please see the attached cause exception "Cannot close the PageCache while files are still mapped:

/opt/neo4j-community-3.1.6/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.counts.db.a (1 mapping)

/opt/neo4j-community-3.1.6/data/databases/graph.db/neostore (1 mapping)

/opt/neo4j-community-3.1.6/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.relationshipgroupstore.db (1 mapping)

/opt/neo4j-community-3.1.6/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.schemastore.db (1 mapping)

/opt/neo4j-community-3.1.6/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.labeltokenstore.db (1 mapping)

/opt/neo4j-community-3.1.6/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.labeltokenstore.db.names (1 mapping)

/opt/neo4j-community-3.1.6/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.relationshiptypestore.db (1 mapping)

/opt/neo4j-community-3.1.6/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names (1 mapping)

/opt/neo4j-community-3.1.6/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.relationshipstore.db (1 mapping)

/opt/neo4j-community-3.1.6/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db (1 mapping)

/opt/neo4j-community-3.1.6/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db.arrays (1 mapping)

/opt/neo4j-community-3.1.6/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db.strings (1 mapping)

/opt/neo4j-community-3.1.6/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db.index (1 mapping)

/opt/neo4j-community-3.1.6/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys (1 mapping)

/opt/neo4j-community-3.1.6/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.nodestore.db (1 mapping)

/opt/neo4j-community-3.1.6/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.nodestore.db.labels (1 mapping)".

at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:496)

at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:206)

... 9 more

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot close the PageCache while files are still mapped:

/opt/neo4j-community-3.1.6/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.counts.db.a (1 mapping)

/opt/neo4j-community-3.1.6/data/databases/graph.db/neostore (1 mapping)

/opt/neo4j-community-3.1.6/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.relationshipgroupstore.db (1 mapping)

/opt/neo4j-community-3.1.6/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.schemastore.db (1 mapping)

/opt/neo4j-community-3.1.6/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.labeltokenstore.db (1 mapping)

/opt/neo4j-community-3.1.6/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.labeltokenstore.db.names (1 mapping)

/opt/neo4j-community-3.1.6/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.relationshiptypestore.db (1 mapping)

/opt/neo4j-community-3.1.6/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names (1 mapping)

/opt/neo4j-community-3.1.6/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.relationshipstore.db (1 mapping)

/opt/neo4j-community-3.1.6/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db (1 mapping)

/opt/neo4j-community-3.1.6/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db.arrays (1 mapping)

/opt/neo4j-community-3.1.6/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db.strings (1 mapping)

/opt/neo4j-community-3.1.6/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db.index (1 mapping)

/opt/neo4j-community-3.1.6/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys (1 mapping)

/opt/neo4j-community-3.1.6/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.nodestore.db (1 mapping)

/opt/neo4j-community-3.1.6/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.nodestore.db.labels (1 mapping)

at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPageCache.close(MuninnPageCache.java:616)

at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.pagecache.PageCacheLifecycle.shutdown(PageCacheLifecycle.java:42)

at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:488)

... 10 more

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Exception closing multiple resources

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)

at org.neo4j.io.IOUtils.newThrowable(IOUtils.java:148)

at org.neo4j.io.IOUtils.closeAll(IOUtils.java:139)

at org.neo4j.io.IOUtils.closeAll(IOUtils.java:79)

at org.neo4j.io.IOUtils.closeAll(IOUtils.java:45)

at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.AbstractLuceneIndex.close(AbstractLuceneIndex.java:217)

at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.WritableAbstractDatabaseIndex.close(WritableAbstractDatabaseIndex.java:144)

at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.labelscan.LuceneLabelScanStore.shutdown(LuceneLabelScanStore.java:201)

at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.RecordStorageEngine.shutdown(RecordStorageEngine.java:468)

at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:488)

... 19 more

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Exception closing multiple resources

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)

at org.neo4j.io.IOUtils.newThrowable(IOUtils.java:148)

at org.neo4j.io.IOUtils.closeAll(IOUtils.java:139)

at org.neo4j.io.IOUtils.closeAll(IOUtils.java:79)

at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.partition.WritableIndexPartition.close(WritableIndexPartition.java:85)

at org.neo4j.io.IOUtils.closeAll(IOUtils.java:122)

... 26 more

Caused by: org.apache.lucene.store.AlreadyClosedException: FileLock invalidated by an external force: NativeFSLock(path=/opt/neo4j-community-3.1.6/data/databases/graph.db/schema/label/lucene/labelStore/1/write.lock,impl=sun.nio.ch.FileLockImpl[0:9223372036854775807 exclusive invalid],ctime=2017-08-03T11:49:56.145951Z)

at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory$NativeFSLock.ensureValid(NativeFSLockFactory.java:166)

at org.apache.lucene.store.LockValidatingDirectoryWrapper.deleteFile(LockValidatingDirectoryWrapper.java:37)

at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFileDeleter.deleteFile(IndexFileDeleter.java:732)

at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFileDeleter.deletePendingFiles(IndexFileDeleter.java:516)

at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFileDeleter.decRef(IndexFileDeleter.java:624)

at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.startCommit(IndexWriter.java:4387)

at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.prepareCommitInternal(IndexWriter.java:2860)

at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.commitInternal(IndexWriter.java:2963)

at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.shutdown(IndexWriter.java:1082)

at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.close(IndexWriter.java:1125)

at org.neo4j.io.IOUtils.closeAll(IOUtils.java:122)

... 29 more
```

**HELP ME TO FIND THE PROBLEM AND THE SOLUTION FOR THE SAME**

Comment: The most obvious cause seems to be this : https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/how-to-fix-cannot-close-the-pagecache-while-files-are-still-mapped/ ... did you by any chance do the upgrade with a different user than the one running the database ?

Comment: No, I really don't think so. As We are using community edition, we update the neo4j by deleting the previous version db and taking the backup of the graph.db folder. Installing the new and copying the file in the graph.db file of new neo4j version. So there was no issue of user